# JQuery Birthday Picker showing border

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the Birthday Picker JQuery plugin and it is working fine. The problem is that Im getting a nasty border around the `<div>` and the width of the `<div>` is 100%. Is there any way of changing that?
 I tried this code but with no results:
        `<div class="birthdaypicker" id="birthdate" style="border:none; width:200px;"></div>`
`$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#birthdate").birthdaypicker({});
 });`

Here is the link to the plugin: [Birthday Picker](https://github.com/abecoffman/birthdaypicker/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: No way! _Birthday Picker plugin_

Comment: Why use this plug-in? Is jQuery UI's datepicker functionality (which birthdaypicker basically uses) not enough? What extra is birthday picker doing? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: I don't get any border or 100% width when I tried it: http://jsfiddle.net/jqsF9/1/

Comment: then what else could be the problem?

Comment: It has to be something you set in your CSS, there isn't even a stylesheet that goes with this plugin - so it's all you. Use a debugger (like Firebug, Chrome Inspector, etc.) and check where the styles are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The [birthdaypicker plugin](https://github.com/abecoffman/birthdaypicker) generates the following markup inside your .birthdaypicker div:

```
<fieldset class='birthday-picker'>
    <select class='birth-year' name='birth[year]'></select>
    <select class='birth-month' name='birth[month]'></select>
    <select class='birth-day' name='birth[day]'></select>
    <input type='hidden' name='birthdate' />
</fieldset>
```

You can remove the border from the generated fieldset element by adding the following css:

```
.birthday-picker {
    border: none;
}
```